# Stack Overflow Universal Windows App please!

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I use Windows 10 Mobile on a Lumia, and I'd like to get more than just emails when someone responds. Can the developers here at the site make a Universal Windows App?

EDIT: Windows 10 Mobile is gaining more users, mostly because the main reason no one wanted a Windows Phone in the first place has been or is in the process of being fixed.

1. **None of the popular apps like Instagram, Snapchat, and other popular games are available on Windows Phone.** But now, with the Desktop App Bridge (for those who know how to use it), devs can port Windows Desktop apps can be installed on Windows 10 devices, including Windows Mobile.
2. **Windows Phones (Lumia) are not durable.** Yes, older models, like my Lumia 640, are not the best, but I have yet to damage it. On top of that, Microsoft now makes their own phones to load Windows 10 Mobile onto, with full Continuum, Cortana, Windows Hello, and cloud service support.

In short, Windows Mobile may not be popular now, but with more and more apps being developed using the Universal Windows Platform, developers can reach all Windows 10 users in one project. **This would be a great investment in the future of technology, and we should go for it.**
On top of that, **making a Universal Windows app will also reach Xbox, Hololens, Desktop, Mobile, and Surface users**. Anybody for it now?

Comment: "I use Windows 10 Mobile on a Lumia" Hey, that's *my* line!

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one. ; )

Comment: Over at the [network meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270100/se-windows-10-universal-app), Shog9 opines that a dedicated app just for notifications could be a worthwhile endeavor, since there simply aren't enough W10M users (especially compared to WP8.x users) to justify the cost of developing a mobile app, and the site already works well enough for desktop and tablet users. That said, I'd happily lend a hand on an official app if I could...

Comment: You're probably the only *two*… ;)

Comment: I'm surprised this is being downvoted. I'd expect either a "meh" or a "yes please" reaction, not a "no no no". Would be interested to hear concrete arguments *against* this proposal (apart from "resource drain"?).

Comment: @deceze There's at least 3 of us!

Comment: @Stijn Inching closer to a critical mass there…

Comment: *The door crashes open... Snow driven by howling winds whips into the interior from the grey winter barren beyond.  A lone figure in heavy furs limps in, struggles to close the door against the gale, and collapses as it closes.  The form is shrouded in the returning dark, his outline barely illuminated by fireplace coals that lay smoldering across the cabin. A face appears in the dark, illuminated by the glow of an old, battered Lumia Icon. His face is weary, and shows advanced aging caused by hardship and heart break. The man looks at the small group gathered in the cabin.* @Stijn Four.

Comment: Why is "resource drain" not a sufficient objection? There is only one benefit in an application versus just using the mobile site, and that is to get notifications. But everyone already has notification fatigue, and there is just no concrete advantage in making Stack Overflow notifications *even more visible*. If you want to check your notifications, just visit the website. I'd rather see the developers focus on improving the mobile site and the main site that *everyone* use, rather than developing a series of applications for every mobile platform.

Comment: @CodyGray Resource drain is a fine reason, but I'd expect only Stack Inc. to have an informed opinion on that. I doubt most downvoters here are Stack employees, so I wonder if they have other reasons.

Comment: Why would only employees need to be concerned with a resource drain? No one has unlimited resources, and it seems perfectly reasonable for the users of the site to have a preference on where limited resources are allocated. Anything else seems downright naive, in fact. @deceze

Comment: @Cody *If* all twelve Phone users turned up and made a great case for this plight and HQ agreed that it's a worthwhile endeavour, they could hire one or two people to do it, that's not such an unreasonable project scope. Even the iOS and Android apps are (un)maintained by about as many people. Resources could be allocated to this without draining them elsewhere if absolutely necessary. (I'm partly playing devil's advocate here, I'm just interested if there are reasons beyond resource considerations.)

Comment: But now you're spending money…and to satisfy 12 users? That doesn't seem smart. Why can't we spend that money to improve features that more users want and/or that will make more money for the company? Surely the VC investors will have something to say about that. And it's not unreasonable to me to suppose that *users* have something to say about that. I certainly do. There a ton of [feature-request]s here on Meta that I'd rather two new hires work to address than spending their time writing a Windows Phone app with features that are redundant with the website.

Comment: Your reasoning is optimistic, but ultimately irrelevant. Stack Overflow is a web app first and foremost. It's already accessible to all desktop users. What developers are doing with their desktop-only apps is irrelevant. So is the "durability" of Windows Phones - my Lumia 830 is still in excellent condition, but among other things, Windows 10 Mobile still has occasional screen tearing on my device where WP8.1 does not (have you ever seen *screen tearing on a smartphone*?!). The software is an inconsistent, unreliable mess, and I'm not sure how salvageable the situation really is to be honest.

Comment: I still think a notifications applet would be a great addition for Windows users, even on the desktop, but with an already well-made web app and an API that's extremely limited in comparison, the universal aspect just doesn't seem nearly as enticing in making a case for implementing features already available on the web.

Comment: *"Windows 10 Mobile is exploding"* – Bad choice of words after the Samsung debacle…

Comment: I was not saying that we should make a UW app for Stack Overflow, I meant that was one of the reasons people wouldn't want Windows Phones. Because this is no longer a valid argument, people might get more Windows Phones.

Answer (score 8):

An official UWP app is not in the pipeline, there aren't enough users to warrant spending any time on it. There is an unofficial client available: [Stackie](https://stackapps.com/questions/7062/stackie-a-stack-exchange-client-for-the-universal-windows-platform). Give it a try and give the developer some feedback if you want to.

In the same vein, when there are bugs on the mobile site that only affect WP8 Internet Explorer and/or W10M Edge, it's unlikely to get fixed. There are no developers at Stack Overflow who have a WP8/W10M device, so they have no easy way of reproducing and fixing the bug. [Source](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5186486#5186486):

> So, the problem here is that a bunch of us own Android devices. Nobody has a Windows Phone [...] I'd love to look into these, but I have no way to even try to reproduce, nevermind fix. [...] Might be a way to do this through an emulator... I haven't tried, so no idea if that's feasible, but probably worth a shot?

Comment: `In the same vein, when there are bugs on the mobile site that only affect WP8 Internet Explorer and/or W10M Edge, it's unlikely to get fixed. ` I totally get not building an app for an underused platform, but not even fixing *browser* bugs on the platform sucks. :( Testing display bugs on devices you don't own has become trivial with services like [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah there are other ways, but with the mobile site already having a low priority (from a user perspective), I guess investigating other options like Browserstack also has a low priority. I've added the source, info came from Adam Lear.

Comment: I am sure if you dropped a line to Microsoft they would happily donate you a device (or two) for testing things.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: Yeah, they're pretty great at that. Failing that though, the Windows Mobile emulator browsers are pretty good at emulating all the issues that come with actual devices.

Comment: If testing is the issue, I'd gladly test builds on my own phone.

Comment: I will happy to help in any matter , while app development for uwp